# Idiomatic "clean" task in npm/yarn/package.json world

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Most build automation tools have `clean` task / target *by convention or built-in* (GNU Make, SCons, Ant, Gradle).

Modern JS tooling (`npm`, `yarn`, `npx`) tend to create directories:

```
build/
dist/
node_modules/
```

I cannot find any policies/usages about command names that remove `build`/`dist` or `node_modules` dirs.

Is `rm -rf build` a canonical cleanup?

Is there a widespread name, like "clean" for:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "npm run generate-build-version",
    "prestart": "npm run generate-build-version",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "clean": "rm -rf build/"
  }
```

Note that `rm -rf` is not cross-platform (hello Windows!) and I need some help from modern JS build platform here... I'm not sure that https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-webpack-plugin is the answer.

Comment: Consider utilizing the [shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx) package for cross-platform. Your `clean` script can then be redefined as `"clean": "shx rm -rf build/"`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `rimraf` as a cross platform tool for cleaning folders with their content: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf. (It is actually a cross-platform alternative for `rm -rf` command.)

I would install it as development dependency with `npm install rimraf --save-dev`.
And after that create the clean script in the `package.json` like

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rimraf build"
}
```

The above example be executed with `npm run clean` and it removes the `build` folder. I think the naming `clean` for the script is fine, most commonly these scripts are named as `clean`.